# Cursorline became black when cursor is moving

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, vimscript-lua

If I change the colorscheme by `<option>`+`12345`

```
:colorscheme newsprint
```

Then when I will firstly got the expected result:

[image]

But then if I move my cursor by `j`/`k`, the clean cursorline gone:

[image]

I can give you bounty if you know how to fix this. This has caused me so much time.

---

The version I'm using:

```
NVIM v0.6.0-dev+452-gb3e0d6708
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
```

Comment: Don't customize a highlight group in a Filetype autocommand: use the colorscheme event instead, and create the autocommand before setting the colorscheme. Also, why the `autocmd!`? Normally one only uses that in an `augroup`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Yes I also think that `autocmd!` should not be set like that. What I want to do is to clear those `au ...` set by a troublesome colorscheme.

Comment: The colorscheme has autocommands?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: I have set `set nocursorline` but when I moved the cursor, the ogly black background cursorline is set :/

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: I've updated my question entirely with pictures. Some plugins are removed but I still got the same result. Which plugin set the autocmd to change the `CursorLine`?

Comment: Does `:verbose autocmd` help identify where the autocommand is coming from?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Exactly. I resolved it yesterday. It's a plugin called `nvim-cursorline` that caused this issue. Thanks for your helps~

Comment: Feel free to self-answer!